# JavaScript how to check if a property is missing in a json

Tags: javascript, json

i'm having some trouble in finding a way to check if in a parsed json object is present a property.
For example  in my js i have this line of code:

`jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonResponse)`

I wanna check if in the jsonArray object there is the property `media`.

For example if my json look like this one:

```
Object0 {hashtags: Array[0], 
         symbols: Array[0],
         user_mentions: Array[1], 
         urls: Array[0]}
Object1 {hashtags: Array[1], 
        symbols: Array[0], 
        user_mentions: Array[0],
        urls: Array[1], 
        media: Array[1]}
```

i wanna check if `Object0` has property `media` and if `Object1` has property `media`.

Thank's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if (Object0.hasOwnProperty('media')) {
    // Object0.media
}
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property. Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method. This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

Comment: ^1, this is the more correct answer because what if the property was explicilty set to undefined? :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE JSON doesn't have a concept of `undefined`, so that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've parsed the JSON, it becomes a normal JavaScript object and you should use the `hasOwnProperty` method to check whether the property exists.

Since JSON objects don't have a property or any complicated inheritance like other JS objects can, all properties that exist will be their own and return true with a hasOwnProperty check:

```
var data = '...';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is `undefined` using [typeof()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) like

```
if(typeof(Object0['media']) == 'undefined'){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already parsed it, it should just be

```
jsonArray.media
```

or

```
jsonArray["media"]
```

to call the property. If you don't need to get the property, but just check it, you can do:

```
jsonArray.media === 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(object0['media'] !== undefined){
//media property present
}else{
//media property not present
}
```

Do same for object1

Comment: if the value is an empty string (""), 0, or false, this will register as the property is not present. All of those could be valid values for the property though.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow you are right, I've fixed the if check, but Tushar's approach is a better way to check.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I had the same question.  An answer for beginners like me:

If statements, testing for just a value that's undefined, is the same as false.

The example code below returns:

"yes animals"

"yes animals.dog"

"nope --- animals.dog.fleas"

```
    const animals = {
      dog: {
        name: 'Rover'
      }
    };
    
    if ( animals ) {
      console.log( "yes animals" );
    }
    
    if ( animals.dog ) {
      console.log( "yes animals.dog" );
    }
    
    if ( animals.dog.fleas ) {
      console.log( "yes animals.dog.fleas" )
    } else {
      console.log( "nope --- animals.dog.fleas" )
    }
```